# Privilege Identity Management (Azure)

Tags: azure, security, identity, elevated-privileges

Is it possible to make different users have different maximum activation duration time for the same role in Azure. For example, User A has the user administrator role with a maximum activation time of 8hrs, and User B also has the user administrator role with a maximum activation time of 24hrs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but not without creating two (2) PIM groups.

One for 8h and one for 24h.
Alternatively, you can use one for 24h and tell the user A that the person can maximum use it for 8h, which means he/she would have to adjust the hours every time they activate. You can then setup a KQL query in your LAW (if you send Entra ID logs) and then create an alert for when User A activate this role. This is not a very good and recommendable solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/id-governance/privileged-identity-management/pim-resource-roles-configure-role-settings?wt.mc_id=MVP_323223